# Whats the difference between the gcloud and google-cloud modules in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

As the title says,

Can someone explain to me what the difference between these two modules are?

```
python -m pip install gcloud
```

vs

```
python -m pip install google-cloud
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to know what changed in the versions as the package moved from gcloud to google-cloud (and then on to google-cloud-*)? My guess would be that is in the git change history, does that give any indication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It went from [gcloud](https://pypi.org/project/gcloud/) to [google-cloud](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/) and later to google-cloud-*

It is now strongly recommended to install the [specific](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python) [google cloud](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) package you would like to use with your application, as the google-cloud package has been deprecated.

[gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) is now a command-line tool that comes with the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)